# error in R CMD build when editing c function in R package

Tags: r

I have modified a C function in the `phmm` package. Now I want to rebuild the package, but the following error occurred. How can I fix the error?

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/phmmw
$ R CMD build phmm
* checking for file ‘phmm/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘phmm’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to re-build vignettes
      -----------------------------------
* installing *source* package ‘phmm’ ...
** libs
*** arch - x86_64
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2 -c arms.c -o arms.o
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [arms.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘phmm’
* removing ‘/private/var/folders/r0/9qv15p6j59j6jtfq775k6j380000gn/T/RtmpIPgvDE/Rinst48317ea7/phmm’
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have gcc version 4.2 which it is after (look in `/usr/bin` for a `/usr/bin/gcc-4.x`). If you do have it somewhere, then add it to your $PATH. You *might* be able to create a symlink called `gcc-4.2` that actually points to a later version and see if the library will compile with the later version, but that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee The version of my xcode is 4.2. How could I add it to my $PATH?  I am not familiar with C.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, not `xcode` the version of your compiler, `gcc`. Try type in `gcc --version` in your command line and you probably have a newer one. The error message you're getting in your package is that it can't find version 4.2. Try also typing in `which gcc-4.2` and see if the executable is anywhere. Suppose the executable was  `/usr/local/asdf/gcc/bin/gcc-4.2`, to add it to your $PATH you'd type `export PATH=/usr/local/asdf/gcc/bin:$PATH` and then do your `R CMD` again. (This just tells your system where to find the program `gcc-4.2`).

Answer (score 1):

Your R installation was configured with `gcc` in such a (suboptimal) was that the `gcc-4.2` command was hardwired.

So you need to

- either provide a command `gcc-4.2`, most commonly done via a symlink from `gcc` to `gcc-4.2`,
- or change the R setting, presumably in the file `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf` where you need to look for `CC`
- or change it on the fly by doing `CC=gcc R CMD build phmm`

You may need to modify more than just one `CC` setting, possibly `CXX`, `LD` and more.  It may be as easy as always removing the  `-4.2` part.

Comment: Very good to hear! In that case it is common here to 'accept' the correct answer by clicking on the tick-mark symbol only you (as the person asking the initial question) can see.